# Keep big sized data received from clients until processed

Tags: c#, azure, servicebus, azure-service-fabric

I have service fabric with the following services:

1. Stateless web-api that receives requests, when each request has a byte array of 1MB.
2. Service that processes the data and writes it to Azure's storage account.

I receive a lot of data from multiple clients and I want to insert it to a set of queues (Azure Service Bus), so that each of the services (in 2.) will process it after receiving it from the queue.

**The problem** is that I can't store messages above 250K in the queue.

What is the best practice to storage those 1MB chunks of data until they are processed and saved in Azure's storage account?

The naïve solution:

> A single instance micro-service that holds the data in the state manager and only a reference will be saved in the queue.

This solution breaks the micro-service architecture, because it's not scalable.

Help please?

Comment: Why not just write to Azure Storage from Web API?

Comment: I have X micro services... they can't all handle the web-api requests at the time that the requests has arrived.
I don't want the client to timeout, so I store the request in a queue, so that it will be processed by the X services, when they are free to handle it.

Comment: Yes, but why do you think sending 1MB to a queue is faster than storing it to Azure Blob?

Comment: State Manager queue? probably. Service Bus queue? maybe. I need the fastest store for the data, until I will be able to deal with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with Mikhail that writing each request to blob storage from the Web API layer is the right solution. You would then queue a reference to the blob and your second tier service instances would dequeue those references and process each blob in turn.

This is a fairly common pattern in distributed systems... there is a cost to each 1 MB request to blob storage, but there's no free lunch. Unless you want to do the request processing right in the web tier you need to save the request data *somewhere*. It sounds like you've already decided against processing in the web tier... that's generally good advice but it depends on the nature of the processing, your anticipated request volume, VM capabilities, etc.

I don't love the idea of using stateful actors/services in Service Fabric to hold the 1 MB request payloads, for the simple fact that it will get expensive to scale your cluster as request count (and needed RAM) grows. Factor in reliable replication of that 1 MB state across the cluster (or eschewing replication and waiting for the inevitable problems) and this is almost certainly a bad idea, relative to other options.

Good luck!

Comment: So you suggest that I will write the data chunk to a storage account, queue the reference and when I would like to add the chunk to a different blob on a different storage account, I will load the data to the memory. write it to the blob and delete the chunk from the storage account?
I will have to write each chunk to the storage account twice.

Comment: you can copy from blob-to-blob efficiently using the AzCopy utility https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-use-azcopy/

Comment: I need to copy blob-to-block-in-blob not blob-to-entire-blob, because I receive 1MB chunks of a blob.

Comment: Building a blob from blocks in that "temp storage" is exactly what I do in the "real storage". So, I'll be handling the requests directly.